# Is there a way to shorten a MySQL query, which is made of a lot of conditionals?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT field 
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = 'x' OR 
      column2 = 'x' OR 
      column3 = 'x' OR 
      column4 = 'x'...
```

Now there are lots of columns to check for the same value. Is there any way I can shorten this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE 'x' in (column1, column2, column3, ....)
```

Comment: Nice - but I suspect the real issue is that the schema is not normalised.

Comment: Some sites have a "search all fields" function, or "search all checked fields".  It's possible that this is useful in a real-life situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mysql Fulltext search feature.

Here is query you can use in your code with full-text:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
WHERE MATCH (yourcolumn1,yourcolumn2,...)
AGAINST ('your texts to search' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Note : You should apply fulltext index on columns in which you want to search.

You can make query with like with combination of AND OR Conditions :

```
select * from table
where
match (column1, column2, column3)
against ('xxx' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html